# Hide details for health indicators in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot health indicator from an actuator. So far example response looks like:

```
{
   "status":"DOWN",
   "details": {
      "diskSpace": {
         "status":"UP",
         "details": {
            "total":499963170816,
            "free":250067189760,
            "threshold":10485760
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Because I need to make `/actuator/health` endpoint public, I need to hide details for health indicators, so I expect to get something like this:

```
{
   "status":"DOWN",
   "details": {
      "diskSpace": {
         "status":"UP"
      }
   }
}
```

For disk space it's not a big problem but e.g. for database I don't want to share exception message and details in case of it's outage. Also (as I mentioned at the beginning) it must be public so I don't want to make this endpoint 'when-authorized'. And at the end - it would be great if it's possible to do that without writing my own custom endpoint.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: You're saying `management.endpoint.health.show-details=when-authorized` won't work for you? Seems like a good use case for the setting: it will show only the summary of the health checks to anonymous visitors, and only provide details for requests that have authorization.

Comment: Configuring it this way would not help me too. The case is that I need information about status of subsystems for supervisor system which is not able to authorize. That's why I need info about subsystems on public endpoint without authorization. And because it's public, I don't want to share implementation details on it (exception messages).

Comment: `when-authorized` should hide the details of each health check when there is no authorization, so I'm not sure I follow your concern with exposing implementation details. Regardless, it sounds like you need to write your own endpoint if the provided one isn't meeting your needs.

Comment: @BartekN Hi i have added comments below please try this approach. thnx

Comment: Have you tried disabling actuator's health endpoint and then creating a custom endpoint by creating a bean that returns Endpoint<String>. Internally that bean code would call actuator's health endpoint, get the data and then strip off whatever you don't want to display and show the rest. I don't think you can pick and chose data from actuator's endpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible at the time of writing (in Spring Boot 2.1 and earlier) without writing your own custom endpoint. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15076) to consider it as an enhancement for a future version of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to achieve this in Spring Boot 2.X

```
management:
  health:
    db:
      enabled: false
    diskspace:
      enabled: false
    mongo:
      enabled: false
    refresh:
      enabled: false
```

More information can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators

Answer (score 0):

I had similary task today Why don't you try this

In application properties File, Disable the Components of diskSpace like this

`management.health.diskspace.enabled=false`

then I created My custom DiskSpaceHealthIndicator Like This:

```java
/**
 * Custom Response Generator of Health diskSpace Conponent status
 * 
 * "diskSpace": {
 *           "status": "UP",
 *           "details": {
 *               "total": "100%",
 *               "exists": true,
 *               "threshold": 8388608000,
 *               "used": "41%",
 *               "free": "59%"
 *           }
 *    } 
 */
   @Component("diskSpace")
   public class CustomDiskSpaceHealthIndicator extends DiskSpaceHealthIndicator {
    
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomDiskSpaceHealthIndicator.class);
  
   private File path;
   private DataSize threshold;
   
    /**
     * new File("/") - means root Path, if we want we can pass custom Path
     * DataSize.ofMegabytes(8000) - we have set thresHold to be 1 Gb
     * @param path
     * @param threshold
     */
    public CustomDiskSpaceHealthIndicator() {
       // new File("/") - represents root Path
        // DataSize.ofMegabytes(8000) - Kept My threshold to 1 Gb 
        super(new File("/"), DataSize.ofMegabytes(8000) );
        this.path = new File("/");
        this.threshold = DataSize.ofMegabytes(8000);
    }
    
    /**
     * we Override Default doHealthCheck Method of DiskSpaceHealthIndicator
     * for given Path we fetch getUsableSpace
     * if diskFreeInBytes >= this.threshold.toBytes()
     * we say Status is Up else Down
     * we fetch Total free Space from path
     * calculate percentage of free Space ,usedSpace and set in Map
     * set ThresHold and  send Response
     * <p>
     */
    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
        long diskFreeInBytes = this.path.getUsableSpace();
        if (diskFreeInBytes >= this.threshold.toBytes()) {
            builder.up();
        }
        else {
            logger.warn("Free disk space below threshold. Available: {} bytes 
            (threshold: {})", diskFreeInBytes, this.threshold);
            builder.down();
        }
        // Skip These if you don't  need response, In My case I needed 
        // response  details in percentages 
         
        long total = this.path.getTotalSpace();
            
        double freePrecentage = ((double) (diskFreeInBytes) / total) * 100;
        double subtract = total - diskFreeInBytes;
        double usedPercentage = ((subtract/total)*100);
            
       
        Map<String, Object> customDiskDetails = new HashMap<>();
        customDiskDetails.put("total", "100%");
        customDiskDetails.put("free", Math.round(freePrecentage) +"%");
        customDiskDetails.put("used", Math.round(usedPercentage)+"%");
        customDiskDetails.put("exists", this.path.exists());
        customDiskDetails.put("threshold", this.threshold.toBytes());
        builder.withDetails(customDiskDetails);
   }
```